# Backend for Java exception reporting GUI

Tags: java, reporting-services, exception, error-reporting

Very frequently I see error reporting GUIs in commercial software. This includes the whole gamut of commercial software: games, enterprise apps, office apps, etc.

For some of my company's software I would like to provide exception reporting GUIs if (and ultimately when) my application fails unexpectedly. Building the GUI is not hard. It boils down to this: ***Are there any existing solutions for the backend systems in exception reporting?*** Ideally I am looking for a java library and a corresponding server backend. I could roll my own solution; for example, I could send the data to a webserver via POST data.

I feel like a solution for this already exists somewhere -- I just haven't run into it. Any recommendations?

Edit:

Example frontend GUI for a user. I need a library to manage the backend of the error reporting. (I won't need user login functionality, just basic reporting.)

[image]

Comment: So you are looking for a feedback button on your default error page?

Comment: I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement the backend for the 'submit error' button. I could, for example, send data in request to a web page via POST data. Or I could interact with some SOAP service. Ideally there is a library floating around that already does this kinda thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no common existing solutions in exception reporting because of specific features of every project. Some projects need to send report using simple HTTP, someone uses web services, someone makes a file report.

I've found old [post](http://codepimpsdotorg.blogspot.com/2008/08/netbeans-exception-reporting.html) where author suggest to extract error reporting code from Netbeans and make independent project from it.

Anyway, there is no problem to implement error reporting tool yourself. You could use HttpClient of JAX-WS (if you have a rich client) or you could use AJAX (if you have a web client) for sending reports.

Implementation is strongly depend of what kind of communication do yo use if tour project, what kind of project, what kind of front-end do you use and etc. It's really hard to implement common library for all projects.

Comment: It is hard to believe that there is no commercial solution including this feature.  Your suggestions are all on the money though.  Its also a good idea to make the bug reporting tool an independent server from your web app (for obvious reasons).

Comment: I think it could be very interesting project.

Answer (score 1):

> **Are there any existing solutions for the backend systems in exception reporting?** Ideally I am looking for a java library and a corresponding server backend.

Have a look at [Ctrlflow Automated Error Reporting](https://www.ctrlflow.com/automated-error-reporting/), which is a software-as-a-service backend to send error reports to. Your frontend GUI would then use one of the [available Java libraries](https://github.com/codetrails/ctrlflow-aer-client/) to communicate with your Ctrlflow Automated Error Reporting instance.

To get a good overview of the backend’s feature set (which may offer more than you need), take the [product tour](https://www.ctrlflow.com/automated-error-reporting/product-tour/). Or just log into the [demo server](https://demo.ctrlflow.com/) to get a feel for the backend.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This product has an instrumentation feature that allow you to track the exceptions by sending the data to a portal : http://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/overview. These features were added to the 6.7 release.
Although it is an obfuscator, you can turn those features off and just use the instrumentation features to send the data or use the APIs directly.
PS - this is my company's product.